# Change text view text based on phone language without using string resources

Tags: java, android, html

How can I change the text within my textview based on the language set on the device without using string resources? I don't want to use string resources. As an example could someone please tell me what code I can use if the device language is in French and whether or not I'd need to use `else if` or `else` for including other languages.

```
TextView txt = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.WCBank_textView1);
txt.setText(Html.fromHtml("<font color='#E32017'>Red apples,</font>" +
                "<font color='#FFD300'> yellow bananas,</font>" +
                "<font color='#00782A'> green grapes</font>"
));
```

Comment: "I don't want to use strings as I know what I'm doing" -- considering that your code sample uses strings, perhaps you might explain exactly what "I don't want to use strings" means. Do you mean string *resources*?

Comment: I meant string resources - prefer to do hardcoding

Comment: Try [`Locale.getDefault()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Locale.html#getDefault%28%29).

Comment: I was thinking more of an if statement tbh. Something like this: `if Locale.getDefault("fr") { txt.setText(Html.fromHtml("<font color='#E32017'> Pommes rouges,</font>" +
                "<font color='#FFD300'> bananes jaunes,</font>" +
                "<font color='#00782A'> raisins verts </font>"
));

};`

Comment: You prefer `if` statements spread over your code over string resources? Why???

Comment: @Jan Because the way some things are said in different languages are not exactly in the same word arrangement as the English language. E.g. Northern and Victoria lines in French would be Lignes Northern et Victoria. The word arrangement is different. Besides I only intend to use this once within my project + what I'm asking for can be done it's just the matter of how to do it.

Comment: @CommonsWare `Locale.getDefault()` won't fully work in this situation as I also need to specify what to show in the text box for specific languages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I still prefer string resources for i18n (not for the individual words, but for the whole expression). That said, you could try something like this:

```
if (Locale.getDefault().equals(Locale.FRENCH) || Locale.getDefault().equals(Locale.FRANCE)) {
    // do the french stuff...
    txt.setText(...);
} else if ...
```